# parsing a datetime with timezone to DateTimeOffset behaves differently according to the machine local settings

Tags: c#, json.net, timezone, utc, datetimeoffset

calling an api with this date:

2021-01-09T21:13:00 **+00:00**

or

2021-01-09T21:13:00 **+01:00**

i got this date into the api converted in different way depending to the local settings of the macchine, is it possible to isolate this behavior and get the date always in UTC time zone?

```
public class Movimento
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ExperimentalConverter))]
        public DateTimeOffset MyDate { get; set; }
        .......

}



public class ExperimentalConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DateTimeOffset) || objectType == typeof(DateTime);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        /*
                =============IF MY MACHINE LOCAL TIME IS SET TO UTC + 01:00  ========================
                i got "09/01/2021 21:13:00" -->  when the client call the api passing --> "2021-01-09T21:13:00+01:00"
                i got "09/01/2021 22:13:00" -->  when the client call the api passing --> "2021-01-09T21:13:00+00:00"

                 =============IF MY MACHINE LOCAL TIME IS SET TO UTC (UTC +  00:00)  ========================
                i got "09/01/2021 20:13:00" -->  when the client call the api passing --> "2021-01-09T21:13:00+01:00"
                i got "09/01/2021 21:13:00" -->  when the client call the api passing --> "2021-01-09T21:13:00+00:00"
         */
        var parsedData = (DateTime)reader.Value;   // 09/01/2021 21:13:00  when the api pass "2021-01-09T21:13:00+01:00"

        //i need a way to uderstad if the received date is in UTC format or UTC+01:00 indipendently from the local settings of the machine, so i can later riapply the offset i need 
        //"parsedData.Kind" give me always the value Local (because the date in this method is already translates according to the local settings of the machine 
        
        .......
    }
```

Comment: A cast of a `DateTimeOffset` to a `DateTime` always seems to use a `DateTimeKind` of unspecified, which makes it end up formatting as local. If the reader is storing the value as a `DateTimeOffset`, then you should cast it to that, and then use the `UtcDateTime` property to keep it as UTC if that's what you're trying to do. `DateTime`/`DateTimeOffset` casting behaviours have caused me many headaches over the years.

Comment: @MartinCostello  `(DateTimeOffset)reader.Value` gives me error, so i tried  `DateTimeOffset.Parse(reader.Value.ToString());` in this way isn't  the timezone lost?

Comment: With `Parse()` you should use the overload that takes a `DateTimeStyles` value. Then you can control how time zones are handled (e.g. `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal`): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.parse?view=net-5.0#System_DateTimeOffset_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you parse a `DateTimeOffset` the offset will be retained.  But unfortunately, when you apply a `JsonConverter` to a `DateTimeOffset` property the `reader.Value` will (with the default settings) contain a `DateTime` where the offset has already been affected by the computer's local time zone.

To work around that, set `DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset` in the serialization settings.

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset
};
```

Then `reader.Value` will contain a `DateTimeOffset` and you can just unbox it.

Also, you can use `JsonConverter<T>` to simplify your code, and you don't need to handle `DateTime` parsing (unless there are other requirements not described in your question).

```
public class UtcDateTimeOffsetConverter : JsonConverter<DateTimeOffset>
{
    public override DateTimeOffset ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, DateTimeOffset existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // First get the DateTimeOffset exactly as presented (asserting never-null)
        var value = (DateTimeOffset) reader.Value!;

        // Then convert it to UTC before returning it.
        return value.ToUniversalTime();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, DateTimeOffset value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Convert the value to UTC and write it to JSON using a Z suffix
        writer.WriteValue(value.UtcDateTime);      
    }
}
```

I've also given you a `WriteJson` implementation that makes sense for this sort of thing, using a `Z` instead of `+00:00` in the output JSON.

[Working example here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TRIjX6)